# Convert to datetime - See all data raising exceptions

Tags: python, pandas

Let's suppose that I am running the following lines in `python` and `pandas`:

```
# Load data
data = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/user/Desktop/data.txt',\
                   keep_default_na=True, sep='\t', na_values='?')


# Convert to datetime column
data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Date'], errors='raise', dayfirst=True)
```

However, I want to see all the data of this column raising exceptions in pandas.

For this reason I wrote this:

```
exceptions = []
for index, row in data.iterrows():

    try:
        row['PICKUP_DT'] = pd.to_datetime(row['PICKUP_DT'], errors='raise', dayfirst=True)

    except:
        exceptions.append(row['PICKUP_DT'])


dataframe = pd.DataFrame({'Exceptions': exceptions})

dataframe.to_csv('C:/Users/user/Desktop/EXCEPTIONS.csv', index=False, na_rep='NA')
```

Is there any better way to do this?

I actually thought that there would be an in-built `pandas` way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.loc` to get all of the problematic rows checking `.isnull()` for the result with `errors='coerce'`. I exclude `NaN` as `pd.to_datetime` will not raise an error for null values.

#### Sample Data

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy a np
data = pd.DataFrame({'Date': [np.NaN, '12-03-2019', '001111231', '46-06-1988']})
#         Date
#0         NaN
#1  12-03-2019
#2   001111231
#3  46-06-1988
```

#### Code:

```
data.loc[pd.to_datetime(data.Date, errors='coerce', dayfirst=True).isnull()
         & data.Date.notnull(), 'Date']
#2     001111231
#3    46-06-1988
#Name: Date, dtype: object
```

Comment: This is an interesting idea, thanks (upvote). However, I am not sure that it is more efficient than mine.

Comment: @PoeteMaudit it doesn't iterate over the rows, so it should be far better.

Comment: Ok cool thanks. (I guess that 'pd.to_datetime' does iterate but I have not seen the source code so I do not know.)